# Netbeans autocompletion don't work anymore even I clear cache

Tags: caching, netbeans, autocomplete

since a few days netbeans do not auto-complete class and function, this is very annoying,  because I work ona huge project with thousands functions/class-methods...

I already tried to delete cache in the user netbeans directory. No effect, it make a background scan but still don't work when done.

I tried also tu create a new project, and checking out my working copy in a new directory ( never used in netbeans ) don't work.

The funny thing is that at home it works correctly with the same project and same version of netbeans.

It make me crazy...

Any suggestion ?

Thank you

Comment: What version NB are you using? Have you tested another one, *without* importing any settings?

Comment: Are there any exceptions in your netbeans log file?

Comment: @ollo I have tested several versions, it is the same issue :(

Comment: @wumpz I found that in the logs : 

WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]
Lucene Index Folder: C:\Users\OA-IT\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0beta\index\s4\php\23\1
Lucene Index Folder: C:\Users\OA-IT\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0beta\index\s4\php\23\1
Caused: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2043

Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: @wumpz and also

ALL [null]: Lucene Index Folder: C:\Users\OA-IT\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0beta\index\s4\php\23\1
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.GsfHintsProvider]: SemanticHighlighter: Cannot get document!
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: class org.netbeans.modules.csl.navigation.ClassMemberNavigatorSourceFactory$ProxyElementScanningTask ignored cancel for 185 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.semantic.MarkOccurrencesHighlighter]: MarkOccurencesHighlighter: Cannot get document!

Comment: In your log Netbeans 8beta is mentioned. Do you have this problem with 8 Release as well?